# ADO.NET vs EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Can someone please explain the difference between ADO.NET and Entity Framework in layman's terms?
I have searched from Google but can't understand the difference.

ADO.Net means using `sqlConnection();`, `sqlCommand();` etc. to interact with database using queries?
Entity Framework means using `db.Add();`, `db.SaveChanges();` functions to interact with database without using queries? Am I right?

Comment: ef is based on ado.net, and can be treated as some wrapper.

Comment: @LeiYang, yes i have read that thousand times.. please tell me is that correct what is wrote in question.. ?

Comment: that is only the surface, it's common syntax, but not necessarily.

Comment: so last question.. if someone asks me to create crud in asp.net using ado.net without using EF then what he wants me to do for interaction with database?

Comment: sqlconnection, sqlcommand,sql statements as you mentioned

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use EF `db.Add();` or `db.SaveChanges` or any other integrated EF method, the ORM (object-relational mapper), in this example EF, will use ADO.NET (so EF will open database connection using ADO.NET, EF will create "SQL query" using ADO.NET,...).

Of course, you can do this all by yourself, using ADO.NET methods, which sometimes can increase the performance of the queries, but usually needs more code writing.

But in general, when you use EF, you also use ADO.NET, only its implemented inside EF methods.